# function declaration conflicting with itself

Tags: php, drupal-7, wamp

I am getting a strange error when trying to declare a simple function in drupal 7.  I am declaring a function at the top of a template file (I know, typically a no no, but I need to get these templates out quick, no time to develop a module for the functions right now.)  So I am declaring the following at the top of the file:

```
1. function templateB_EventRegistrationNode($params = NULL) {
2. /* code */
3. }
```

However when I try to run the template I am getting the following error,

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare templateB_EventRegistrationNode()
>   (previously declared in
>   C:\wamp\www\vsi\sites\all\themes\vsi_new_template_b\templates\node.tpl.php:1)
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\vsi\sites\all\themes\vsi_new_template_b\templates\node.tpl.php
>   on line 3

(Line numbers have been changed to match example.)

Anyone have any Idea why the first line is conflicting with the last line of the function?  BTW, a carbon copy of the function with a different name works in another template, so the code is valid.

Comment: probably because template files can be included multiple times, and the second inclusion is causing the error.

Comment: The line numbers are irrelevant (as is your obscuring so for the example). It's the function redeclaration which is the problem. Use deferred definitions by wrapping it in `if (!function_exists("...")) {` at the very least.

Comment: awesome, thanks guys, that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal, any function used by a theme template file should go in the template.php file used by the theme.

@mario is right about the error being caused by the file being included more than once, but if you put the functions in the template.php file, the error will not appear anymore, since that is included only once.

The content of a template file should just be the code necessary to show the output.

Comment: I think that is a rookie mistake, without thinking I added a tiny function is my *.tpl.php file. Strangely enough it was working with no error on my local vagrant but failing on my test server. Definitely one of those thing you won't doing wrong twice.